# laravel LoginController::showLoginForm doesnt exist

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

i am working on a laravel project.
i generated the auth files through terminal.
installed Socialite and everything was working fine.

that was yesterday
today i was working at a view and how to pass some variables from a controller
then i tried to open the login page and got the error:

```
Method App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController::showLoginForm does not exist.
```

i looked up the LoginController and looked for the function showLoginForm. It was really not there. But it says

```
use AuthenticatesUsers;
```

so i followed it and found the function.
But i cant figure out why this mistake is appearing.
in my LoginController i have

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
...
use AuthenticatesUsers;
```

what did go wrong that the login isnt working anymore? i didnt touch anything regarding the login/routing

```
 <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Socialite;
use App\User;
use Auth;
use Log;
use Session;

class LoginController extends Controller
{

use AuthenticatesUsers;

protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

public function __construct(){
    $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
}

public function redirectToProvider($provider)
{
    return Socialite::driver($provider)->redirect();
}
public function handleProviderCallback($provider)
{
  switch ($provider) {
    case 'google':
      $userSocial =   Socialite::driver('google')->stateless()->user();
      $users       =  User::where(['email' => $userSocial->getEmail()])->first();

      if($users){
        //user gefunden und wird eingeloggt
        Auth::login($users);

        Log::error('dawdw');
        Log::error($users->site_url);

        return redirect($users->site_url);
      }else{
        $max_id = User::max('id');
        $user_site = strtolower($userSocial->user['given_name']).$max_id;

        $user = User::create([
                    'lastname'      => $userSocial->user['family_name'],
                    'firstname'     => $userSocial->user['given_name'],
                    'email'         => $userSocial->getEmail(),
                    'image'         => $userSocial->getAvatar(),
                    'provider_id'   => $userSocial->getId(),
                    'provider'      => $provider,
                    'user_status_id'=> 1,
                    'site_url' => $user_site
          ]);
      }
      Auth::login($user);
      return redirect()->route($user_site);
      break;

    default:
      // code...
      break;
  }



    // $users       =  User::where(['email' => $userSocial->getEmail()])->first();
    // Auth::login($users);
    // print_r($user);
    // $user->token;
}
}
```

Comment: when run `php artisan route:list` you must have route like the following,    `GET|HEAD  | login                         | login            | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm                | web,guest    |` this line exists ?

Comment: i tried php artisan route:list and yes the line with showLoginForm is shown there

Comment: You didn't change anything on LoginController, right ? And just you are trying to access `/login` url and getting error, right ? Also can you run  `composer dumpautoload` command please.

Comment: i tried composer dumpautoload but the error is still the same. i realized i also had a LoginController outside the auth folder. I deleted it cause i didnt use it

Comment: Can you send me your Login Controller please, Are you sure namespace is correct ?

Comment: i edited it in the question

Comment: Please change your question into an actual question (i.e. it should end in a question mark).  If this is a bug in Laravel or one of its available components, please report bugs to the appropriate repository.

Answer (score 0):

There's two different 'use' statements that you need.

The first one is at the top of your file (after namespace) :

`use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;`

The second one is inside your `LoginController` class :

```php
class LoginController extends Controller
{

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    // the rest of your code.

}
```

There is often confusion between these two.

The first one tells PHP you want to use the file. The second one tells php you want to "use the methods from that file" (these are called [Traits](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php)).

Comment: thx for the explanation but i figured it out myself. I have both lines in my controller and still have the error.